# Taskbar extensions not working in Ubuntu 18.10 with gnome 3.30

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10, gnome-shell-extension, taskbar

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10. But after I updated it broke the  [Taskbar extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/). And I tried other taskbar extensions too. All are not working. Is there any solution to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally make it work. I think gnome-extension page have old one. I referred
the github repo and there was a issue and patch for that. I clone the repository and copy it to extension folder. After I logout and login it worked perfectly. Use following commands.

```
git clone https://github.com/jimmytheneutrino/gnome-shell-extension-taskbar
cp -r gnome-shell-extension-taskbar/ ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/TaskBar@zpydr
```

Before copy ,remove any old versions from `gnome-shell-extension-taskbar/ ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/TaskBar@zpydr`.